# Click animation using GSAP

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

So this is a GIF of the effect I want to accomplish: **[Link](https://gyazo.com/732fdf564f4cd403cfd75d40299860ba)**.

Sorry about the lack of quality of the GIF but it was the best I could do. So, this the code that gets executed when I click the 'Next Task' button:

```js
var tasks = [
  ["First Task...", 2],
  ["Second Task...", 4],
  ["Third Task!", 6]
];

function nextTask() {
  var previousText = $("#taskText").text();
  $("#nextTaskButtonWhite").remove();
  $("body").append("<div id='nextTaskButtonWhite'></div>");
  $("#nextTaskButtonWhite").bind("click", nextTask);
  TweenMax.to("#nextTaskButtonWhite", 0.5, {
    opacity: 0
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#nextTaskButtonWhite").remove();
  }, 500);
  do {
    var randTaskNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tasks.length);
    $("#taskText").text(tasks[randTaskNum][0] + tasks[randTaskNum][1]);
  } while (previousText == $("#taskText").text());
}
```

```css
/*These are the classes and IDs I use*/

.button {
  background-image: url("Pattern2.png");
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s;
}
.button:hover {
  background-image: url("Pattern3.png");
}
#nextTaskButton {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#nextTaskButtonWhite {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

For now it works, but it gets a little finicky and weird when I click the button lots of times in a row. My question is: using **GSAP** and **jQuery**, is there a way to make this work well in a simpler way? Possibly not having to use a second white button to do it?

Thanks to anyone that answers!! :-)

Comment: honestly, utilizing css transitions is probably your best bet. you won't get the wonky behavior from spamming the button.

Comment: yeah but can i do it with gsap? i'd love to know

Comment: Why you are making gsap do button transitions. Do it for animation purposes, spamming sites with unnecesary 100kB libraries is not a good thinking, and you can do it with gsap using css property inside your statement. But CSS Transitions are enough for simple tasks

Comment: how would i do it with css transitions then?

Comment: can you post a fiddle please with your HTML, CSS and JS? seems like an easy thing to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JocaPinto: http://jsfiddle.net/asaboyef/.

Comment: @TahirAhmed you the best thanks!

Comment: @JocaPinto: glad it helped :)